# How to automatically open a C# script when creating one in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I create a script it automatically opens visual studio but I was wondering if there was a way to automatically open the specific script that I just created?

Comment: Well if you create it in VS, VS will open it for you.  Other than that, if you create it Unity-side, you just need to double-click it.   Did you configure Unity to have VS to be the default external editor for C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems is that when you add a new script, it has to add it to the visual project project by regenerating the project. It also triggers Unity to recompile. They should improve this but this is probably why they can't instantly open it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should do it automatically. Check if there is a message in Visual Studio above the tab bar that says something about the unity integration gone wrong. It should have a link to a guide on how to set it up properly.